# IIS Express fails to start VS2010sp1 project

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2010

I have a sporadic issue whereby occasionally when I boot my computer, open a solution and start the debugger for a project set to run under IISExpress, that IE opens and shows a diagnose connection problem message.  The Output window only shows:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> The program '[4556] iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The program '[4556] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I am running IISExpress w/ Studio 2010 SP1 with MVC3 on Windows 7 (32-bit).  Most days my system will start up and everything works fine.  Occasionally after a reboot or cold start, the above happens.  Typically when I am wireless only (but it has been a while since I've been hardwired).  I've tried turning off the wireless card and re-enabling it and that does not change things either.

Typically the only thing I can do is switch back to the studio dev server for a while.  Later when I go back to IISExpress it is fine again. (however just toggling the setting does not immediately fix the issue).

I am at a loss on how to debug what is happening. I have looked at my appplicationhost.config and it hasn't changed in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any custom bindings to the applicationhost.config file at all? How does your machine get its ip address? is it DHCP? I found issues with my iis when my machine was assigned a new ip address which had been previously hardcoded in the config file. Do you normally laucnh VS in administration mode? This can also affect the avialability of the ports.